# What is the best way to denote a set of solutions in a professional setting?

Tags: number-theory, notation, diophantine-equations, real-numbers, coordinate-systems

I have the following Diophantine equation that I want to solve over the positive (real) integers:

$$x^2+y^2=x+9y\tag1$$

> Questions:
>
> 1. I want to solve this equation for real positive integers bigger than or equal to 2. How do I write that mathematically?
> 2. When I find the solutions I got: $(x,y)$ can be $(5,4)$, $(5,5)$ and $(1,9)$. How do I write that mathematically that those are the solutions?

---

I think that the answer to question 1 is:

$$\left(x\in\mathbb{N}\space\wedge\space x\ge2\right)\space\wedge\space\left(y\in\mathbb{N}\space\wedge\space y\ge2\right)\tag2$$

I think that the answer to question 2 is of these three notations:

\begin{align}
(x,y)&=(5,4),(5,5),(1,9),\tag3 \\
(x,y)&=\{(5,4),(5,5),(1,9)\},\tag4 \\
(x,y)&\in\{(5,4),(5,5),(1,9)\}.\tag5
\end{align}

Comment: ($2$) is okay, and I like $(5)$

Comment: First of all thanks for your comment. Are those also the  professional way of writing it?

Comment: This is an issue that is between you and your publisher / reviewer(s) / editor(s) / instructor(s) / etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be (5) because (3), (4) imply $(x,\,y)$ is *equal to* its set of possible values rather than *an element of* that set.

Comment: I don't see a problem with (3). It is how I would personally write it, anyway.

Comment: @YiFan The problem with (3) is its use of $=$, because $(x,\,y)$ is equal to either the first or second or third of those listed $2$-tuples, not to... whatever a comma-separated list of them is meant to denote.

Comment: Okay, I can agree that this notation is *technically* not very rigourous, but regardless its meaning is very much clear. There is not really any risk of confusion regarding the indended meaning there, and the commas in between the items in the list just mean "or".

Comment: @YiFan Even $a=b\lor c$ is not the same as $a=b\lor a=c$. And what if there had been only two solutions? Might the statement have been misinterpreted as giving unique values, each $2$-tuples, to each of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Again, I agree with you in a technical sense, and I'm not suggesting that the comma literally means $\lor$. But writing solutions in this way (e.g. writing $x^2=1\iff x=1,-1$) is *extremely* common, and I don't see a serious risk of misinterpretation. See Yves Daoust's answer, for example.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably write

1. $n,m\in\mathbb N:n,m\ge2$ (equivalently $\mathbb Z$),
2. $(n,m)=(5,4),(5,5),(1,9)$.

If you want a truly "professional" way, such as in a math review, you need to adhere to the conventions of that particular publication.

Comment: How can $(1,9)$ be in the solutions if you search for $n \ge 2$?

Comment: @RiccardoAllegrone: I am not fixing the exercise (nor solving), I am answering about the notation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = \mathbb{N} \setminus{\{0\}}.$ You can write the set of solutions as

$$S = \{(x,y) \in A\times A \;|\; x^2+y^2=x+9y\}=\{(5,4),(5,5),(1,9)\}.$$

Notice that if you require $x \ge 2$, then you can't include the pair $(1,9)$.